# Hazelcast [3.2.6] Client cannot connect when SSL is enabled

Tags: hazelcast

I have a simple use case where the one node should be able to publish message to another using topics. I am able to do this with a simple client-server mode of communication in Hazelcast. However when I enable SSL on client and server I get this exception on client side

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get initial partitions!
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientPartitionServiceImpl.getInitialPartitions(ClientPartitionServiceImpl.java:100) ~[hazelcast-client-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientPartitionServiceImpl.start(ClientPartitionServiceImpl.java:60) ~[hazelcast-client-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.start(HazelcastClient.java:223) ~[hazelcast-client-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
    at com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(HazelcastClient.java:186) ~[hazelcast-client-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
```

and the server prints the following in logs

```
09/29/2014 14:40:06.806 [hz.defaulttenant-defaultorg0.IO.thread-Acceptor - platform] INFO  c.h.nio.TcpIpConnectionManager - [x.x.x.x]:5702 [defaulttenant-defaultorg0] [3.2.6] Established socket connection between /x.x.x.x:5702 and /x.x.x.x:55831
09/29/2014 14:40:16.844 [hz.defaulttenant-defaultorg0.IO.thread-Acceptor - platform] INFO  com.hazelcast.nio.SocketAcceptor - [x.x.x.x]:5702 [defaulttenant-defaultorg0] [3.2.6] Accepting socket connection from /x.x.x.x:55832
09/29/2014 14:40:16.845 [hz.defaulttenant-defaultorg0.IO.thread-Acceptor - platform] INFO  c.h.nio.TcpIpConnectionManager - [x.x.x.x]:5702 [defaulttenant-defaultorg0] [3.2.6] Established socket connection between /x.x.x.x:5702 and /x.x.x.x:55832
09/29/2014 14:40:21.847 [hz.defaulttenant-defaultorg0.IO.thread-Acceptor - platform] INFO  com.hazelcast.nio.SocketAcceptor - [x.x.x.x]:5702 [defaulttenant-defaultorg0] [3.2.6] Accepting socket connection from /x.x.x.x:55833
09/29/2014 14:40:21.847 [hz.defaulttenant-defaultorg0.IO.thread-Acceptor - platform] INFO  c.h.nio.TcpIpConnectionManager - [x.x.x.x]:5702 [defaulttenant-defaultorg0] [3.2.6] Established socket connection between /x.x.x.x:5702 and /x.x.x.x:55833
```

I have enabled SSL on server side via config xml

```
       <ssl enabled="true">
            <factory-class-name>com.hazelcast.nio.ssl.BasicSSLContextFactory</factory-class-name>
          <properties>
            <property name="keyStore">cert.jks</property>
            <property name="keyStorePassword">password</property>
            <property name="keyManagerAlgorithm">SunX509</property>
            <property name="trustManagerAlgorithm">SunX509</property>
            <property name="protocol">TLS</property>
          </properties>
       </ssl>
```

and the client uses following code to access server

```
                ClientConfig clf = new ClientConfig();
                clf.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("x.x.x.x:5702");
                clf.getGroupConfig().setName("grp-name");
                clf.getGroupConfig().setPassword("password");

                clf.getNetworkConfig().setSSLConfig(NodeCommUtil.getSSLConfig());

                clf.getNetworkConfig().setSocketOptions(socketOptions);

                HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clf);




public static SSLConfig getSSLConfig() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException,
        IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    SSLConfig sslConfig = new SSLConfig();
    sslConfig.setEnabled(true);
    sslConfig.setFactoryClassName("com.hazelcast.nio.ssl.BasicSSLContextFactory");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    ClassPathResource r = new ClassPathResource("cert.jks");
    props.setProperty("keyStore", "/" + r.getFile().getAbsolutePath());

    props.setProperty("keyStorePassword", "password");

    props.setProperty("keyManagerAlgorithm", "SunX509");
    props.setProperty("trustManagerAlgorithm", "SunX509");
    props.setProperty("protocol", "tls");

    sslConfig.setProperties(props);
    return sslConfig;
}
```

Both client & server are able to communicate with each other. And in fact if I disable SSL works like charm. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SSL has been removed.

Which HZ version are you using on the server btw?

Comment: I am using HZ V 3.2.6 [non-enterprise] http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.2/manual/html/ssl.html

Comment: I've noticed something very strange, it works fine when client and server are on the same machine. However in a distributed setup I keep getting this exception.